# npm not installing bower on OSX 10.10.1

Tags: npm, osx-yosemite

Anybody know how to fix this?

`/Users/foo $npm install -g bower`

`npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower`

`npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower`

`npm http fetch GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz`

`npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz`

`npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0`

`npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"`

`npm ERR! node v0.12.0`

`npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1`

`npm ERR! path /Users/foo/.node/bin/bower`

`npm ERR! code EACCES`

`npm ERR! errno -13`

`npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/foo/.node/bin/bower'`

`npm ERR!     at Error (native)`

`npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/foo/.node/bin/bower'`

`npm ERR!   errno: -13,`

`npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES'`

`npm ERR!   path: '/Users/foo/.node/bin/bower' }`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

`npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink'/Users/foo/.node/bin/bower'`

`npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)`

`npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/foo/.node/bin/bower']`

`npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,`

`npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',`

`npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/foo/.node/bin/bower' }`
``
`npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:`

`npm ERR!     /Users/foo/npm-debug.log`

`/Users/foo$echo $PATH`

`/Users/foo/.npm:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin`
`:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Comment: Have you managed to solve this weird errors? I'm stumbling into same issues when trying to set up a simple dev machine on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it as Root user? try

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

The npm ERR! code EACCES usually results because it didn't have permission to access a necessary folder or file